# Amount of integer multiplications performed with matrices - how much faster?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am trying to determine how much faster a multiprocessing system would be at multiplying matrices than a single processor system.

Here is my thought process/example:

Assume Matrix A is *k x l* and Matrix B is *l x m*.
The matrix product of *AB* is *k x m* matrix *C*

Every entry in matrix C is a scalar product which requires *l* multiplications (and *l - 1* additions).

In a single processor system, this would require *l x km* number of entries.

In a multiprocessing system with *km* processors(where all of this would be done in parallel), this would only require *l* integer multiplications.

To me, this means that the multiprocessing system is *km* times faster. Is this correct, or is there more to it than that?

Comment: You need to tell us how many processors your multiprocessing system has! (Also, each entry in $C$ requires $l$ multiplications, not $l^2$.)

Comment: Oops -- the multiprocessing system has _km_ processors

Comment: Then you should edit that information into your question. (And fix the $l\times l$ problem while you're at it.)

Comment: thanks, it has been updated

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have at least $km$ processors you are (roughly) right, depending on the time it takes to assemble the results from all the processors.  You have $km$ entries in the result to compute and you could have each processor compute one of them.  If you want all the results in a single array on one processor you need to communicate with it.  How that compares timewise with the multiplications depends very much on your system.

If you have $2km$ processors you could imagine sharing one result entry across two processors.  Each one would do half the multiplies and adds, then one of them would do the final addition.